# Is it possible to disable the "nowrap" option on pymode?

Tags: wrapping

I installed pymode plugin but it overrides my default setting (`set wrap`). According to `:verbose set wrap?`, the option is set by pymode.

However, I'm not sure if it is possible to override the setting. I could not find how it is done in [the plugin Github repository](https://github.com/python-mode/python-mode).

Comment: Could you link to the plugin? Makes it easier to find.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Added!

Answer (score 2):

Typically, one can override settings for file types with `.vim/after/ftplugin/{filetype}.vim`, so,

```
" .vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim
setlocal wrap
" dont forget about b:undo_ftplugin (1)
```

Alternately, the plugin may provide a configuration variable (check its help documentation) that controls application of such settings.

In this case, you may want `let g:pymode_options = 0`

---

1. For `b:undo_ftplugin`, I recommend my approach [here](https://github.com/benknoble/Dotfiles/blob/master/links/vim/autoload/ftplugin.vim), especially if (like me) you maintain a fair number of filetype-specific settings.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know which directory to use in Neovim?

Comment: `~/.config/nvim/after/ftplugin/python.vim`, i think